# Reactive form / Text area - No of characters remaing <using i18n>

Tags: angular

Have done follow. code for textarea remaining char validation and corres display message:

```
 <textarea class="col-sm-12" maxlength="2000" rows="8" formControlName="comments"
                                #comments  i18n-placeholder="@@describecomments"></textarea>
                                <span class="col text-right text-warning"><em>{{ 2000 - comments.length }} characters left</em></span>
```

This display weired msg:

[image]

However, I have used below  with template driven form and it works perfectly:

```
 <textarea class="col-sm-12" maxlength="10000" id="medHistoryComments" rows="5" [(ngModel)]="medHistoryComments" i18n-placeholder="@@describemedHistoryComments" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></textarea>
      <span class="col text-right text-warning"><em>{{ 10000 - medHistoryComments.length }} characters left</em></span>
```

Where it went wrong with reactive form?

Comment: Post the error as text also!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`comments` is the name of your **formControl**, you need to access it's `value` property in order to get what you want, unless you have a variable explicitly set to track that formControl, you would need to access the **formGroup** first.

**UPDATE**

This is how you should access the formControl

```html
<textarea class="col-sm-12" maxlength="2000" rows="8" formControlName="comments"
          i18n-placeholder="@@describecomments">
</textarea>

<span class="col text-right text-warning"><em>{{ 2000 - medHistoryForm.controls['comments'].value.length }} characters left</em></span>
```

**UPDATE 2**

```html
<textarea class="col-sm-12" maxlength="2000" rows="8" formControlName="comments"
          i18n-placeholder="@@describecomments">
</textarea>

<span class="col text-right text-warning"><em>{{ charactersLeft }} characters left</em></span>
```

```js
INITIAL_CHARACTERS = 2000;

export class Component implements OnDestroy {
  charactersLeft: number;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.charactersLeft = INITIAL_CHARACTERS;
    this.medHistoryForm = formBuilder.group(...)

    this.subscription = this.medHistoryForm.controls['comments'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.charactersLeft = INITIAL_CHARACTERS - value.length;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the html of your whole form?

Comment: Sorry...It works patially...Count is shown correctly...However it doesnt decrement at all on entering the data...<form [formGroup]="medHistoryForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"> <div class="col-sm-12"> <span>Comments</span>   <textarea class="col-sm-12" maxlength="2000" rows="8" formControlName="comments"                                #comments  i18n-placeholder="@@comments"></textarea>                                <span class="col text-right text-warning"><em>{{ 2000 - medHistoryForm.controls['comments'].value.length }}  characters left</em></span>                        </div>   </form>

Comment: @NewbieAngular check the updated answer, this should refresh the value every time there's a change.

Comment: Works perfectly...!! ..Great help indeed..Thank a ton!.